# Updating OpenLayers ZoomToExtent control

Tags: openlayers, error, extents, update, mapcontrol

I have OpenLayers control defined like,

```
// Zoom to Extent control
var zoomToExtentControl = new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({ extent: [73.19, 15.12, 81.80, 22.77] });
```

Which will give us Extent button on Map Screen

[image]

We have created on function which will zoom to map extent when we pass extent values from API call, which is working fine, but we are trying to update value of `Extent` button value to new extent value using `_extent` params which is not working, what we are missing here or is there any method. using `updateParams()` or else

```
  // On Dropdown Change event
  function zoomToOptionExtent(_extent) {
    Map.getView().fit(_extent, { duration: 1600, size: Map.getSize() - 200 });
    // zoomToExtentControl.setExtent(_extent);
    zoomToExtentControl.setProperties({ extent: _extent });
  }
```

Though we tried the alternative that will directly remove control and adding it again with the updated value, but we don't think it will be appropriate

```
  // On Dropdown Change event
  function zoomToOptionExtent(_extent) {
    Map.getView().fit(_extent, { duration: 1600, size: Map.getSize() - 200 });
    // Remove the existing zoomToExtentControl from the map
    Map.removeControl(zoomToExtentControl);

    // Create a new zoomToExtentControl with the updated extent
    zoomToExtentControl = new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({ extent: _extent });

    // Add the new zoomToExtentControl to the map
    Map.addControl(zoomToExtentControl);
  }
```

Comment: Please [Edit] your Question to ask a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a named variable for the array used to construct the control

```
var extent = [73.19, 15.12, 81.80, 22.77];
var zoomToExtentControl = new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({ extent: extent });
```

You can update it using the array splice method

```
// On Dropdown Change event
function zoomToOptionExtent(_extent) {
  Map.getView().fit(_extent, { duration: 1600, size: Map.getSize() - 200 });
  extent.splice(0, Infinity, ..._extent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick reply, this works fine, but our question is can we update control value it self without adding new control or removing it from map controls?

Comment: ` 
// Zoom to Extent control
var extent = [73.19, 15.12, 81.80, 22.77];
var zoomToExtConst = new ol.control.ZoomToExtent({ extent: extent });
`  
and updating its values using @Mike method 
`
// On Dropdown Change event
  function zoomToOptionExtent(_extent) {
    Map.getView().fit(_extent, { duration: 1600, size: Map.getSize() - 200 });
    // You can update it using the array splice method
    extent.splice(0, Infinity, ..._extent);
  }
`

Comment: The control only needs to be added to the map once, only the array it uses needs to be updated.

Comment: as mentioned in previous comment, it is working fine, but we are looking for method of openalyers itself like UpdateParams or something else

Comment: The only methods available are listed in the API `changed dispatchEvent get getKeys getMap getProperties getRevision on once render set setMap setProperties setTarget un unset`  None of those will update the extent.  If an existing property was updateable via `set` or `setProperties` it would also seen in 'getkeys` and `getProperties`.

Comment: That's right, I think it means that some updates are need in OpenLayer itself, marking as acceptable answer, thank you